# Mongo gridfs-stream

Tags: node.js, mongodb

This is my first gridfs-stream work. I am trying to read a file from my local directory (C:\work\node\test.txt) and write it to gridfs-stream. When I run this file, I am getting below error

C:\work\node>node Test
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: ENOENT, open 'C:\work\node\work
ode     est.txt'
    at Error (native)

I have tried to use try-catch also but had the same error. Can any one see the mistake I am making and point out? thanks.

and here is my code..

```
var fs = require("fs"),
    mongo = require("mongodb"),
    Grid = require("gridfs-stream"),
    gridfs,
    writeStream,
    readStream,
    buffer = "";

    mongo.MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/test", function  (err, db) {
   //  "use strict";
    gridfs = Grid(db, mongo);

   // write file
   writeStream = gridfs.createWriteStream({ filename: "test.txt" });
   fs.createReadStream("C:\work\node\test.txt").pipe(writeStream);
  });
```

Comment: Ok. I did not realize the escape characters in my file path. Once I corrected it, it works. I guess i jumped the guns too soon :)

Comment: This is how my corrected file path  looks    fs.createReadStream("C:\/work\/node\/test.txt").pipe(writeStream);

Comment: you should put it as the answer and accept it yourself. might help someone else :)

Comment: how can I accept it as my answer? I don't see accept button/link anywhere.

Comment: you will have to post the answer below, then accept that

Comment: done. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

This works now with the corrected file path

```
   var fs = require("fs"),
   mongo = require("mongodb"),
   Grid = require("gridfs-stream"),
   gridfs,
   writeStream,
   readStream,
   buffer = "";

   mongo.MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/test", function   (err, db) {
 //  "use strict";
   gridfs = Grid(db, mongo);

  // write file
  writeStream = gridfs.createWriteStream({ filename: "test.txt" });
  **fs.createReadStream("C:\/work\/node\/test.txt").pipe(writeStream);**
 });
```